# Zend2 - ZF2 - Routing Issue

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route

i am trying to make my router working so that:

```
/Auth redirects to Auth controller of Auth MOdule
/Auth/Login redirects to Login controller of Auth Module
```

While the first works just right the /Auth/Login results in routing issue.

My router configuration file looks like below:

```
     'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'Auth' => array(

             'type' => 'literal',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/Auth',
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Auth\Controller\Auth',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'Auth/Login' => array(
                        'type' => 'literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/Login',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Auth\Controller\Login',
                                'action' => 'index')
                    ),
                ),
            ),
         ),
     ),
 ),
```

Comment: Code looks okay, although you probably don't want the `/` in the login route name (just called it `Login` rather than `Auth/Login`). What is the routing error that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit this section

```
   'child_routes' => array(
        'Auth_Login' => array(
           // ... your existing codes
```

Just remove `/` from `Auth/Login` and use hyphen `-` or `_` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in @TimFountain his comment. Because you named the child route `Auth/Login` you will have to request `Auth/Auth/Login` to get a match.

As soon as you rename the child route to `Login` you will get the route match as expected on `Auth/Login`.